# SQL Server Split Row To Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, split

I'm working on a query that would split one row to multiple rows.
I have the following as the result of my query:

```
     TEXTVALUE
1    Product1 P5 Product2 P19 Product3 P30 Product4 P11 Product5 P23
2    Product3 P30 Product7 P33 
3    Product8 P53 Product5 P23 Product1 P5
```

I need to output this into:

```
     PRODUCT         AMOUNT
1    Product1        P5
2    Product1        P5
3    Product2        P19
4    Product3        P30
5    Product3        P30
6    Product4        P11
7    Product5        P23
8    Product5        P23
9    Product7        P33
10   Product8        P53
```

Regardless of duplicates, I just need to basically split them between the product name and the amount.

Any good pointers please?

Thanks so much!

Comment: where is the data stored in such a manner?  Hopefully not already in a table?  Are you getting this in a file? Can they not provide a CSV or pipe delimited file?  What happens if a product name has P# in it?  Can products have a space?  There is a lot of information you haven't provided that you need to think about before you'll be able to get an answer (I would guess)

Comment: Good points. The thing is they store this in a table. Their software would accept the list and then store it in the database as a single row. I believe they have validation that would handle any unnecessary characters. Products does not have space. They're basically ItemCodes but I just represented them as names in the question so it would be easier to read. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is just an awful way to handle data as it violates 1NF and causes nothing but intense amounts of pain. You will have to split this data into rows using a splitter. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: One thing to keep in mind - most TSQL splitters are basic 'split on comma or space' deals; looking at this you'll want to remember to split on what appears to be every other space value, and then possibly again on space to get each individual field.  Or at least recognize you have nested data elements in your source!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I agree. That's why it's a pain trying to generate reports with the kind of design they have. Thanks for the link! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer the method listed in the linked article above referred to as the Moden splitter. I do NOT use the version that Aaron modified so that his comparison was consistent. I use the original as posted here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ You will need to view that page and get the code for that splitter before this code will work.

One big advantage that splitter has over most other ones is that it returns the row number for the individual item. You can leverage this quite nicely for multiple level splits like you need here.

Here is a complete working example using the tally table splitter.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#something')is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    SomeID int identity, 
    TextValue varchar(500)
)

insert #Something
select 'Product1 P5 Product2 P19 Product3 P30 Product4 P11 Product5 P23' union all
select 'Product3 P30 Product7 P33' union all
select 'Product8 P53 Product5 P23 Product1 P5';

with MySplitData as
(
    select Item
        , ItemNumber
        , SomeID
    from #Something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.TextValue, ' ') x
)

select p.Product
    , a.Amount
from
(
    select Item as Product
        , ItemNumber
        , SomeID
    from MySplitData
    where ItemNumber % 2 = 1
) p
join
(
    select Item as Amount
        , ItemNumber
        , SomeID
    from MySplitData
    where ItemNumber % 2 = 0
) a on a.ItemNumber = p.ItemNumber + 1
    AND a.SomeID = p.SomeID
order by p.SomeID
    , p.ItemNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

Splitting in this simple case can be done by using FTS world-breaker (if product names contains dashes or other characters which can force FTS parser to split it to several terms - create UDF for splitting, like suggested in previous answer). Getting next value can be done using LEAD windowing function (SQL Server 2012 and upper required. This approach will do only one table scan).

```
CREATE TABLE #t (text nvarchar(100))
GO


INSERT INTO #t VALUES
('Product1 P5 Product2 P19 Product3 P30 Product4 P11 Product5 P23'),
('Product3 P30 Product7 P33'),
('Product8 P53 Product5 P23 Product1 P5');


WITH SplittedData AS
(
    SELECT t.display_term AS PRODUCT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumber,
        LEAD(t.display_term, 1, NULL) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS AMOUNT
    FROM #t
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser('"' + text + '"', 1033, NULL, 1) t
)
SELECT PRODUCT, AMOUNT
FROM SplittedData
WHERE RowNumber % 2 = 1
ORDER BY PRODUCT


DROP TABLE #t
GO
```